How to get site id of One Drive for Business with MS Graph API
I'm struggling to get site id for my one drive link with MS Graph API.
This is my one drive link - https://sharedspace-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/r/personal/naruto/Documents/Shared%20Folders/hinata?csf=1&web=1&e=M3GWjd
and I took the host and site url from the above link.
HOST = r"sharedspace-my.sharepoint.com"
SITE_URL = r"/personal/naruto/Documents/Shared%20Folders/hinata"

I can get the access token as well however, if I try to get site id, I get ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108) error. I confirmed for access and it's accessible.
This is the code I tried.
auth_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'scope': 'files.readwrite.all',
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'response_type': 'code',
    'client_secret': client_secret
}

response = requests.post(auth_url, data=data)
access_token = response.json()['access_token']
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/" + host + ":" + site_url
headers = { "Authorization" : "Bearer " + access_token }
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.content)
site_id = ','.join(data['id'].split(',')[1:])

Am I missing something here?

I think that the correct site URL should be SITE_URL = r"/personal/naruto". You need Sites.Read.All permission to be granted. It doesn't explain the error.

Did you try the same query in Microsoft Graph Explorer?

To get the site ID of OneDrive for Business you can make use of below query as a workaround:
access_token = 'AccessToken'

url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/SharePointIds"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    site_id = data.get('siteId', '')
    print("Site ID:", site_id)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)


Otherwise, make use of below query:
access_token = 'AccessToken'
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/xxx.sharepoint.com:/sites/SiteName"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    site_id = data.get('id', '')
    print("Site ID:", site_id)
else:
    print("Error:", response.status_code, response.text)



